How to load a csv file onto Spark standalone cluster without HDFS?
I'm working with a Spark standalone cluster and I need to load file onto the workers.
I've used SparkFiles, but my file still isn't visible. It's present on the master, but not distributed to the workers. How can I resolve this issue?
Ways to add a file:
pyspark --master spark://ip-address:7077 --files data.csv
from pyspark import SparkFiles
spark.sparkContext.addFile("data.csv")

Screenshots:
Trying to read file on cluster
Read file on master
Logs:
24/05/02 08:22:59 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.5.1
24/05/02 08:22:59 INFO SparkContext: OS info Linux, 6.1.0-18-amd64, amd64
24/05/02 08:22:59 INFO SparkContext: Java version 17.0.10
24/05/02 08:22:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
24/05/02 08:22:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 39319.
24/05/02 08:22:59 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-4abd4519-5b17-418e-9fc4-459d77053d9c
24/05/02 08:23:01 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:///home/user/pycl/data.csv at spark://192.168.101.140:39319/files/data.csv with timestamp 1714627381502
24/05/02 08:23:01 INFO Utils: Copying /home/user/pycl/data.csv to /tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at /home/user/pycl/main.py:18
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at /home/user/pycl/main.py:18) with 2 output partitions
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/user/pycl/main.py:18)
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0), which has no missing parents
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.0 KiB, free 434.1 MiB)
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.9 KiB, free 434.1 MiB)
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 192.168.101.140:43019 (size: 2.9 KiB, free: 434.4 MiB)
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1585
24/05/02 08:23:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1))
24/05/02 08:23:04 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (192.168.101.144 executor 3): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.lambda$openFileWithOptions$0(ChecksumFileSystem.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LambdaUtils.eval(LambdaUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.openFileWithOptions(ChecksumFileSystem.java:894)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$FSDataInputStreamBuilder.build(FileSystem.java:4768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) (192.168.101.144, executor 3, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7914 bytes) 
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) on 192.168.101.144, executor 3: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv does not exist) [duplicate 1]
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (192.168.101.143, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7914 bytes) 
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) on 192.168.101.144, executor 3: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv does not exist) [duplicate 2]
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) (192.168.101.144, executor 3, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7914 bytes) 
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) on 192.168.101.144, executor 3: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv does not exist) [duplicate 3]
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) (192.168.101.144, executor 3, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7914 bytes) 
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) on 192.168.101.144, executor 3: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv does not exist) [duplicate 4]
24/05/02 08:23:04 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 0: Stage cancelled: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) (192.168.101.144 executor 3): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.lambda$openFileWithOptions$0(ChecksumFileSystem.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LambdaUtils.eval(LambdaUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.openFileWithOptions(ChecksumFileSystem.java:894)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$FSDataInputStreamBuilder.build(FileSystem.java:4768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Driver stacktrace:
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/user/pycl/main.py:18) failed in 1,826 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) (192.168.101.144 executor 3): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.lambda$openFileWithOptions$0(ChecksumFileSystem.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LambdaUtils.eval(LambdaUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.openFileWithOptions(ChecksumFileSystem.java:894)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$FSDataInputStreamBuilder.build(FileSystem.java:4768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Driver stacktrace:
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collect at /home/user/pycl/main.py:18, took 1,955981 s
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 192.168.101.143:45353 (size: 2.9 KiB, free: 434.4 MiB)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/pycl/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    for line in file_content.collect():
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1833, in collect
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 179, in deco
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) (192.168.101.144 executor 3): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.lambda$openFileWithOptions$0(ChecksumFileSystem.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LambdaUtils.eval(LambdaUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.openFileWithOptions(ChecksumFileSystem.java:894)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$FSDataInputStreamBuilder.build(FileSystem.java:4768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2856)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2792)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3060)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2463)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1049)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/userFiles-662c691d-20e9-45d3-9a18-a10b3e812116/data.csv does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.lambda$openFileWithOptions$0(ChecksumFileSystem.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LambdaUtils.eval(LambdaUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.openFileWithOptions(ChecksumFileSystem.java:894)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$FSDataInputStreamBuilder.build(FileSystem.java:4768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more

24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.101.143:45353 (size: 32.6 KiB, free: 434.4 MiB)
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.101.140:4040
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-a2ec1106-bbd1-445f-b926-fef93fe5141c
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d/pyspark-533666e3-024e-4161-94eb-9ba51d5b39b4
24/05/02 08:23:04 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-2a2793ea-5d86-4294-bce0-f720aea63d9d

